# How to find center point of 3d convexl hull, 3d polygon or polyhedron (all by Delaunay triangulation) in R

Tags: r, 3d, triangulation, convex-hull, delaunay

Here is the answer to solving the center point of 2d convex hull:
[Centroid of the minimum convex polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890739/centroid-of-the-minimum-convex-polygon)

how to find center point of 3d convex hull(package:geometry) in R?

example for bunny data:

```
library("onion")
library("geometry")
library("rgl")

data(bunny)
bunnyConvexHull <- convhulln(bunny, output.options = TRUE)#convex hull
plot3d(bunny, col = "pink") #bunny poins
plot(bunnyConvexHull, col = "gray", alpha = 0.3, add = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a triangle **rgl** mesh, you can get its centroid with the packages **cgalMeshes**. Unfortunately, this package is not on CRAN currently. You can install it by running (this takes a while):

```r
remotes::install_github("stla/cgalMeshes@github", dependencies = TRUE, build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

To get a **rgl** mesh of the convex hull, I didn't manage to use the `to.mesh3d` function of the **geometry** package. Here is how to get this mesh with the **cxhull** package (also based on the C(++) library **qhull**):

```r
library(cxhull)
# take bunny data from the onion package
data(bunny, package = "onion")
# convex hull
hull <- cxhull(bunny, triangulate = TRUE)
# extract vertices and faces
hmesh <- hullMesh(hull)
vertices  <- hmesh$vertices
triangles <- hmesh$faces
# the triangles are given in terms of the vertex names
# let's transform them to get them in terms of the vertex indices
dict        <- 1L:nrow(vertices)
names(dict) <- rownames(vertices)
triangles <- apply(triangles, c(1L, 2L), function(x) dict[as.character(x)])
# make a rgl mesh
library(rgl)
rmesh <- tmesh3d(
  vertices = t(vertices),
  indices  = t(triangles)
)
```

Finally:

```r
# now let's get the centroid
library(cgalMeshes)
mesh <- cgalMesh$new(rmesh)
mesh$centroid()
# [1] -0.02735468  0.09912979  0.00442025
```

### EDIT

I've finally found how to get the **rgl** mesh with the **geometry** package; the point was to use the `FA` option:

```r
library(geometry)
# take bunny data from the onion package
data(bunny, package = "onion")
# convex hull
hull <- convhulln(bunny, options = "Tv FA")
# make a rgl mesh
rmesh <- to.mesh3d(hull)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You provided a very good implementation method. Thank you very much!

Comment: About geometry package, 'output.options = TRUE' can return p, hull, area, vol, normals  elements, using 'FA' just without normals element. I'm sorry I didn't mention it in detail.